# Issues for data scraping with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So basically i'm trying to scrape jobs website, my goal is to retrieve job title, company, salary, location. Which i'm planning to get into csv file so I could do some plotting of it.
My current code is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page=1'

#Opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML parser 
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
# grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'list_a_wrapper'})

contain = containers[0]
container = containers[0]
print(container.h3)
```

And returns me:

```
<h3 class="list_h3" lang="en">Senior Talent Manager</h3>
```

If I ask: `container.h3['class']` this returns `['h3_class']` , If I ask: `container.h3['lang']`
I get `en` but I can't retrieve  `Senior Talent Manager`

Here is on of the job add HTML code:

```
<div class="list_a_wrapper">
<div class="list_cell">
<h3 class="list_h3" lang="en">Senior Talent Manager</h3>
<span class="heading_secondary">
<span class="dib mt5">UAB „Omnisend“</span></span>
</div>
<div class="list_cell jobadlist_list_cell_salary">
<span class="salary_c">
<span class="salary_bl salary_bl_gross">
<span class="salary_inner">
<span class="salary_text">
<span class="salary_amount">2300-3300</span>
<span class="salary_period">€/mėn.</span>
</span>
<span class="salary_calculation">Neatskaičius mokesčių</span>
</span>
</span>
<div class="salary_calculate_bl js_salary_calculate_a" data-href="https://www.cvbankas.lt/perskaiciuoti-skelbimo-atlyginima-6732785">
<div class="button_action">Skaičiuoti »</div>
<div class="salary_calculate_text">Į rankas per mėn.</div>
</div>
</span> </div>
<div class="list_cell list_ads_c_last">
<span class="txt_list_1" lang="lt"><span class="list_city">Vilniuje</span></span>
<span class="txt_list_2">prieš 4 d.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

So what approach would be the best to scrape: title which is in h3, dib mt5, salary_amount, salary_calculation, list_city.

Comment: show your desired output? otherwise it would be very difficult to figure out what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Note that there is also `soup.find('div', 'list_a_wrapper')` which returns the first instance found.

Comment: I wish to retrieve in one container: Senior Talent Manager,  UAB „Omnisend“,  2300-3300, Neatskaičius mokesčių, Vilniuje

Comment: Also, every node in BeautifulSoup has a `text` property, so soup.find('div', 'h3').text returns the first occurrence of a `div` with class `h3` (the node `<h3 class="list_h3" lang="en">Senior Talent Manager</h3>`) and gets the text which is everything inside this node that is not a tag.

Comment: If above example is the actual structure of the DOM, you could even be fancy and use `result = [entry for entry in soup.find('div', 'list_a_wrapper').text.split('\n') if entry.strip()]` to extract all the text and then specify `job_title = result[0]`, `company = result[1]`, `salary = result[2]` and so on.

Comment: For example : ```salary = container.find_all('span',{"class":"salary_amount"})```    
printed out gives me :  ```[<span class="salary_amount">Nuo 2300</span>]```
while I would need only text  ```Nuo 2300```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will get job title, company, salary, location from the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page=1'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for h3 in soup.select('h3.list_h3'):
    job_title = h3.get_text(strip=True)
    company = h3.find_next(class_="heading_secondary").get_text(strip=True)
    salary = h3.find_next(class_="salary_amount").get_text(strip=True)
    location = h3.find_next(class_="list_city").get_text(strip=True)
    print('{:<50} {:<15} {:<15} {}'.format(company, salary, location, job_title))
```

Prints:

```
UAB „Omnisend“                                     2300-3300       Vilniuje        Senior Talent Manager
UAB „BALTIC VIRTUAL ASSISTANTS“                    Nuo 2700        Vilniuje        SENIOR .NET C# DEVELOPER
UAB „Lexita“                                       1200-2500       Vilniuje        IT PROJEKTŲ VADOVAS (-Ė)
UAB „Nordcode technology“                          1200-2000       Vilniuje        PHP developer (mid-level)
UAB „Nordcurrent Group“                            Nuo 2300        Vilniuje        SENIOR VAIZDO ŽAIDIMŲ TESTUOTOJAS
UAB „Inlusion Netforms“                            1500-3500       Vilniuje        Senior C++ Programmer to work with Unreal (UE4) game engine
UAB „Solitera“                                     1200-2800       Vilniuje        Java(Spring Boot) Developer
UAB „Metso Lithuania“                              Nuo 1300        Vilniuje        BI DATA ANALYST
UAB „Atticae“                                      1000-1500       Vilniuje        PHP programuotojas (-a)
UAB „EIS Group Lietuva“                            2000-7000       Vilniuje        SYSTEM ARCHITECT
UAB GF Bankas                                      Nuo 1200        Vilniuje        HelpDesk specialistas (-ė)
Tesonet                                            1000-3000       Vilniuje        Swift Developer (Security Product)
UAB „Mark ID“                                      1000-3000       Vilniuje        Full Stack programuotojas

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To save as `csv`, you can use this script:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


all_data = []
for page in range(1, 9):
    url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page=' + str(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    for h3 in soup.select('h3.list_h3'):
        job_title = h3.get_text(strip=True)
        company = h3.find_next(class_="heading_secondary").get_text(strip=True)
        salary = h3.find_next(class_="salary_amount")
        salary = salary.get_text(strip=True) if salary else '-'
        location = h3.find_next(class_="list_city").get_text(strip=True)
        print('{:<50} {:<15} {:<15} {}'.format(company, salary, location, job_title))

        all_data.append({
            'Job Title': job_title,
            'Company': company,
            'Salary': salary,
            'Location': location
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: how would you save it with pandas to xlsx?
I made a list:
```results = []``` and also did to all elements in loop like:
 ``` results.append(h3.get_text(strip=True))```  
but when I trying to create:
```df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["Job title","Company","Salary","Location"])
df.to_excel("list.xlsx", index=False)```

I'm getting this:
```ValueError: Shape of passed values is (200, 1), indices imply (200, 4)```

Comment: Thank you for help @AndrejKesely, any ideas why my code stops at https://prnt.sc/toc7qy
Note that I changed a bit url, trying to take all city adds and there is 8 pages of them.

Comment: @EdgarasVaninas I updated my answer. There are ads, where salary isn't specified, so you need to check it.

Comment: Yeah scraped nice, even my xlsx can't display my native language symbols, trying to get LibreOffice. 
And also how would clean Salary objects? as it comes as string which contains one of `Nuo 2700` or `Iki 2500` or has two numbers like `1000-3000`. If there is salary from to some point, should I get mean of them? Because I would like to use Salary column as integers so I could do some plotting with Seaborn.

Comment: @EdgarasVaninas To not clutter the comment section, I recommend to open a new question here on Stack Overflow, where you describe your problem and put there sample input and expected output. You can accept this answer as for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218581/discussion-between-edgaras-vaninas-and-andrej-kesely).

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the text inside the tag with

`title = tag.get_text()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'list_a_wrapper'})
```

Try this:

```
results = []
for i in page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':'list_a_wrapper'}):
   results.append(i.text)
```